# Getting friends update query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have three tables which are members, friends, and updates. I am trying to develop a query that will grab the updates for users who are friends with a specific user. For example get all the updates from all the friends of member X, USER:

```
X   -> friend_1 > updated picture
    -> friend_2 > added friend
    -> friend_3 > updated status

Y   -> friend_1 > updated picture
    -> friend_2 > added friend
    -> friend_3 > updated status
```

FRIENDS

```
friend_index
friend_id
logged_user_id  *
```

MEMBERS

```
display_name
 id             *
```

UPDATES

```
update_id
member_id       *
friend_id
update_action
```

So far this is the query that I have currently this gives me the updates of the current user and not the current users friends.

```
   SELECT
U.update_id,
U.update_action,
U.update_hidden,
U.update_time,
U.member_id,
U.friend_id AS friend,
M.id,
M.display_name AS user,
F.friend_id,
F.logged_user_id
FROM member_friends F
JOIN members M
    ON M.id = F.logged_user_id
JOIN member_updates U 
    ON U.member_id = F.friend_id 
WHERE U.member_id = :id
ORDER BY U.update_id DESC
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: can you more clearify your table structure?

Comment: Where is the table `member_friends` is referenced in your query? you are selecting from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining the member_update with user.id thus leaving out the friends updates in the first join.
I would begin by selecting all the friends and then joining the member_update table with friends table and not user table

Query:

```
SELECT
    U.member_id,
    U.update_action,
FROM members M
    JOIN member_friends F
        ON M.id = F.logged_user_id
    JOIN member_updates U
        ON U.member_id = F.friend_id
WHERE M.id = :id
    AND U.update_hidden <> 1
ORDER BY U.update_id DESC
```

Assuming logged_user_id is the user id which has firends friend_id
UPDATES.member_id is the user id to which that update belongs

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: See edit.. Also it will help if you specified what the id's are in each table

Comment: I'll test it now thanks for checking. Yes your assumption is correct by the way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    U.update_id,
    U.update_action,
    U.update_time,
    U.member_id,
    U.id,
    F.friend_id,
    U.display_name AS user,
    F.display_name AS friend
FROM members M
    JOIN member_friends F
        ON M.id = F.logged_user_id
    JOIN member_updates U
        ON U.member_id = F.friend_id
WHERE M.id = :id
    AND U.update_hidden <> 1
ORDER BY U.update_id DESC
```

Comment: close, but the data set is printing out the same username for friend as the logged user, USER X has updated USER X profile

Comment: @kabuto178 Wath is the `member_id` in `UPDATES` why it set PK (I assume `*` mean PK)?

Comment: correct, when you posted your answer first I did not place the keys so that is where I made you confused XD. This query is really close however because it grabs my friends but in the updates table there is one entry made by one of my friends and it prints out all my friends doing the same one update. Maybe that will give you more insight. member_id is the currently logged in user

Comment: updates table is to store the different activities users do on the site, added pictures or does a status change, so i want to grab the updates done by my friends then join this list to my members table to get their name and their update action. eg. Hamlet Hakobyan responded to katty.. responded to would be in the update_action column, Hamlet Hakobyan would be my friend and katty the user you interacted with